# What's the role of IEnumerable<T> and why should I use it?

Tags: c#, collections, ienumerable

Why should I use **`IEnumerable<T>`** when I can make do with...say **`List<T>`**? What's the advantage of the former over the latter?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work

Answer (score 34):

`IEnumerable<T>` is an interface that tells us that we can enumerate over a sequence of `T` instances.  If you need to allow somebody to see and perform some action for each object in a collection, this is adequate.

`List<T>`, on the other hand, is a specific implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` that stores the objects in a specific, known manner.  Internally, this may be a very good way to store your values that you expose via `IEnumerable<T>`, but a `List<T>` is not always appropriate.  For example, if you do not need to access items by index, but constantly insert items at the beginning of your collection and then remove items from the end, a `Queue<T>` would be far more appropriate to use.

By using `IEnumerable<T>` in your API, you provide yourself the flexibility to change the internal implementation at any time *without changing any other code*.  This has huge benefits in terms of allowing your code to be flexible and maintainable.

Comment: I agree strongly with your point about decoupling from the implementation, but I also think there's a point for making clear the expected usage; even if I have a List<T>, referring to it as IEnumerable<T> makes it clear that the functionality I'm expecting from the collection in that usage is the enumerability functionality, and not any of the other List functionality.  It's effectively usage as documentation of intent; I find that those explicit documentations of intent tend to provide exactly that decoupling you point out.

Comment: @Paul: I agree, though I would suggest `IList<T>` vs. `IEnumerable<T>` in that case, **not** `List<T>`.

Comment: Good point, although that brings up a whole other question of "interface vs. concrete instance", which I think is a different question.

Answer (score 4):

On this point [Jeffrey-Richter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) writes:

When declaring a method’s parameter types, you should specify the weakest type possible, 
preferring interfaces over base classes. For example, if you are writing a method that 
manipulates a collection of items, it would be best to declare the method’s parameter by 
using an interface such as `IEnumerable<T>` rather than using a strong data type such as `List<T>` or even a stronger interface type such as `ICollection<T>` or `IList<T>`:

```
// Desired: This method uses a weak parameter type   
public void ManipulateItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection) { ... }  

// Undesired: This method uses a strong parameter type   
public void ManipulateItems<T>(List<T> collection) { ... }
```

The reason, of course, is that someone can call the first method passing in an array object, a `List<T>` object, a `String` object, and so on — any object whose type implements `IEnumerable<T>`. The second method allows only `List<T>` objects to be passed in; it will not accept an array or a `String` object. Obviously, the first method is better because it is much more flexible and can be used in a much wider range of scenarios.

Naturally, if you are writing a method that requires a list (not just any enumerable object), then you should declare the parameter type as an `IList<T>`. You should still avoid declaring the parameter type as `List<T>`. Using `IList<T>` allows the caller to pass arrays and any other objects whose type implements `IList<T>`.

On the flip side, it is usually best to declare a method’s **return type** by using the strongest type possible (trying not to commit yourself to a specific type).

Comment: Yes, but be careful with `IList<T>` since arrays implement it only partially, i.e. calling `Add` or `Remove` for instance will throw exceptions with arrays.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: Arrays have an even more subtle problem: a `Cat[]` will may be passed as `IList<Animal> myList`, and if `Animal someAnimal` is either null or happens to hold a reference to a `Cat`, `myList[0]=someAnimal` will succeed.  If `someAnimal` is a non-null reference to something other than a `Cat`, however, the operation will fail.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: Short of using Reflection, there's no way of knowing whether an `IList<T>` which allows anything of a given type to be stored by index will allow everything of that type to be stored by index.

Comment: @supercat: Yes, making arrays co- and contravariant is a serious design flaw in my eyes. Also arrays should not implement `IList<T>`. Instead, there should be a `IArray<T>` interface, which `IList<T>` would extend.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: Arrays are covariant only; defining an interface for arrays which would allow an efficient type-agnostic way of permuting them is difficult; simply allowing allowing array covariance is easier by comparison.  What would have been ideal would have been to have multiple storage-location types for arrays (e.g. given S:T:U and `T[] foo; T+[] bar, T-[] boz;`, `foo` could only hold instances of `T[]`, `bar` could hold `T[]` or `S[]`, and `boz` could hold `T[]` or `U[]`) but .NET expects a strong correlation between storage-location types from heap object types.

Comment: @supercat: `IArray<T>` would implement an indexer and a `Length` property. Call-site variance would solve the problem: `void MyMethod(Animal[] out a) { ... }` and `void MyMethod(Cat[] in c) { ... }`. But according to Eric Lippert this would add a great complexity to the C# compiler.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: What sort of variance should a `Sort` routine require, given that it both reads from and writes to a collection?  What would have to happen to allow a method which expects an `ISortableList<Animal>` to accept and sort a `Cat[]` in fully-type-safe fashion?  One approach would be to have `ISortableList<T>` inherit a non-generic `IPermutableList` which includes a type-agnostic `SwapAt` method, but some sorting or other permutation algorithms can be implemented most efficiently if they can read something out and later write it back.

Comment: One could have an `IPermutableList` include a `GetBorrower` method which would returns a type-agnostic `IArrayItemBuffer`, which would in turn have `ReadItemAt`, `SwapWithItemAt`, and `WriteItemAt` methods that would move items between the array and an internal buffer; that could probably be done somewhat efficiently, but would nonetheless be a bit awkward to work with.

Comment: @supercat: When sorting we use only objects that are already in the collection and therefore we know that they can be casted safely to `T`. Moreover, the items do not leave the collection at any time during the sorting if we use a sort method of this collection, therefore variance is not an issue. The items will be treated as `IComparable<T>` or `IComparable` anyway.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: If a sort method reads an `Animal` from an `Animal[]`, it knows that storing that reference back into the array will be safe, but the compiler has no concept of "thing that was read from a particular `Animal` array.  For an interface type to represent the idea of "sortable list of some `Animal` derivative" it would have to either provide a "store `Animal`" method which could fail at runtime if given something invalid, or else provide a type-safe means of reading something from the array and writing it back.

Comment: @supercat: My opinion is that you need covariant arryas only in languages that don't have generics. See [Covariant arrays in Java and C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Covariant_arrays_in_Java_and_C.23) on wikipedia.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: If one has a generic type parameter available which matches the *exact type* of the array, the indicated approach will work.  It would not, however, allow one to add arrays to a heterogeneous collection and then sort them (if one adds a `Dog[]` and a `SiameseCat[]` to a collection of `ISomething<out Animal>`, it should be possible to sort all elements in the `Dog[]`, and all elements in the `SiameseCat[]`, but the only generic type parameter available would be `Animal`).  An array `T[]` could support a type-safe `IPermutableArray<out T>` sufficient to allow sorting...

Comment: ...without having to know the array's exact type (so code which holds a reference of type `IPermutableArray<Animal>` that points to a `SiameseCat[]`, along with an `IComparer<Animal>`, could sort the array without having to know that it was a `SiameseCat[]`, but a flexible and efficient design for `IPermutableArray<out T>` would require some thought.

Comment: @supercat: It is clear that removing variance from arrays would be a restriction, but the question is whether the benefits outweigh the limitations or not. See [Eric Lippert’s Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: I've read Mr. Lippert's blog.  My point was not that array references should be covariant, but rather that arrays should implement or or more covariant mutable interfaces *in addition to* covariant read-only and invariant mutable interfaces.  Sometimes it's helpful to know that a `T[]` can accommodate all things of type `T`, both sometimes it's helpful to be able to have a type which allows at compile-time things that may or may not succeed at run-time.  As another example, ...

Comment: ...a base type may promise that any derived-class implementation of a virtual method (e.g. `WithSomeProperty(xx)`) will return an instance of the same derived type.  If I have a collection of things that inherit from a class that includes the `WithSomeProperty()` method, it would be helpful to be able to say something like `for (int i=0; i<it.size; i++) it[i] = it[i].WithSomeProperty(whatever);`, recognizing that the write could fail at run-time if `WithSomeProperty` violates its contract.  Unfortunately, the only clean way I know to express such a concept...

Comment: ...would be to have `IReadWriteByIndex<out TRead>`, `IWriteByIndex<in TWrite>`, and `IReadWriteByIndex<out TRead, in TWrite>` where TRead:TWrite.  That would work beautifully from a variance standpoint, but there's no way to way for the indexed get to return a `TRead` while allowing the setter to accept a `TWrite`.

Comment: @supercat: OK, got it!

Comment: +1 This is an excellent answer, thank you.  By the way, Richter's reference is on page 233.

Answer (score 2):

Different implementations of collections can be enumerable; using IEnumerable makes it clear that what you're interested in is the enumerability, and not the structure of the underlying implementation of the collection.

As mentioned by Mr. Copsey, this has the benefit of providing decoupling from the implementation, but I'm of the contention that a clear definition of the smallest subset of interface functionality as possible (i.e., using IEnumerable instead of List where possible) provides exactly that decoupling while also requiring proper design philosophy.  That is to say, you can achieve decoupling but not achieve minimal dependency, but you cannot achieve minimal dependency without achieving maximal decoupling.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to build a public API, it's better to use `IEnumerable` than `List<T>`, because you better use the most minimalistic interface/class. `List<T>` lets you access objects by index if that's required.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975426/which-is-better-to-use-array-or-list/2975522#2975522) is a pretty good guideline when to use `IEnumerable`, `ICollection`, `List<T>` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Using the concept of iterators you can achieve major improvement in algorithm quality, both in terms of speed and memory usage.

Let's consider the following two code examples. Both parse the file, one stores lines in collection, the other uses enumerable.

First example is O(N) time, and O(N) memory:

```
IEnumerable<string> lines = SelectLines();
List<Item> items = lines.Select(l=>ParseToItem(l)).ToList();
var itemOfIterest = items.FirstOrDefault(IsItemOfIterest);
```

Second example is O(N) time, O(1) memory. Additionally, even if the asymptotic time complexity is still O(N), it would load twice as fewer items as in the first example on average:

```
var itemOfIterest = lines.FirstOrDefault(l=>IsItemOfIterest(ParseToItem(l));
```

Here is the code of SelectLines()

```
 IEnumerable<string> SelectLines()
 {
  ...
  using(var reader = ...)
  while((line=reader.ReadLine())!=null)
   yield return line;
 }
```

Here is why it loads twice as fewer items as the first example on average. Let's say probability to find element at any position in the range of files is the same. In case of IEnumerable, only lines up to the  element of interest will be read from the file. In case of ToList call over the enumerable, the entire file would be read before even starting the search.

Of course, the List in the first example would hold all the items in memory, that is why O(N) memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you don't use `IEunumerable` directly. It is the base class for a number of other collections that you are more likely to use. `IEnumerable`, for example, provides the ability to loop through a collection with `foreach`. That is used by many inheriting classes such as `List<T>`. But `IEnumerable` doesn't offer a sort method (though you can use Linq for that) while some other generic collections like `List<T>` do have that method.

Oh sure, you can use it to create your own custom collection types. But for everyday stuff, it probably isn't as useful as the collections derived from it.

Answer (score 0):

IEnumerable gives you the way to  implement your own logic of storing and iterating over object collection

Answer (score 0):

**Why implement IEnumerable in your class?**

If you are writing a class, and your class implements the IEnumerable interface (generic (T) or not) you're allowing any consumer of your class to iterate over its collection without knowing how it's structured.

A LinkedList is implemented differently than a Queue, a Stack, a BinaryTree, a HashTable, Graph, etc. The collection represented by your class might be structured in different ways.

As a "consumer" (if you are writing a class, and your class consumes/makes-use-of an class-object that implements IEnumerable) you can use it without concerning yourself how it's implemented. Sometimes the consumer class doesn't care about the implementation - it just wants to go over all the items (printing them? changing them? comparing them? etc.)

(So as a consumer, if your task is to iterate over all items in a BinaryTree class, and you skipped that lesson in Data-Structures-101 - if the BinaryTree coder implemented the IEnumerable - you're in luck! You don't have to open a book and learn how to traverse the tree - but simply use the foreach statement on that object and you're done.)

As a "producer" (writing a class that holds the data-structure/collection) you might not want consumers of your class to handle how it's structured (afraid they might break it, maybe). So you can make the collection private, and only expose a public IEnumerator.

It can also allow for some uniformity - a collection might have a few ways to iterate over its items (PreOrder, InOrder, PostOrder, Breadth First, Depth First etc.) - but there's only 1 implementation for IEnumerable. You can use this to set the "default" way to iterate over the collection.

**Why use IEnumerable in your method?**

If I write a method that takes a collection, iterates over it, and takes action on the items (aggregate them? compares them? etc.) why should I restrict myself to 1 type of collections?

Writing this method `public void Sum(List<int> list) {...}` to sum all items in the collection means I can only receive a list and sum over it. Writing this `public void Sum(IEnumerable<int> collection) {...}` means I can take any object that implements IEnumerable (Lists, Queues, Stacks, etc.) and sum all of their items as well.

**Other Considerations**

There's also the issues of deferred execution and unmanaged resources. IEnumerable takes use of the yield syntax, which mean you go over each item by-itself and can perform all kinds of computations before and after. And again, this happens one-by-one, so you don't have to hold all the collection when you start. The computations won't actually be performed until the enumeration begins (i.e. until you run the foreach loop). And that might be useful and more efficient in certain cases. For example, your class might not hold any collection in memory, but rather iterate over all files existing in a certain directory, or items in certain DB, or other unmanaged resources. IEnumerable can step in and do it for you (you could also do it without IEnumerable, but IEnumerable "fits" conceptually, plus it gives you the benefit of being able to use the object produced in a foreach loop).

Answer (score -1):

Implementation of IEnumerable<T> is generally the preferred way for a class to indicate that it should be usable with a "foreach" loop, and that multiple "foreach" loops on the same object should operate independently.  Although there are uses of IEnumerable<T> other than "foreach", the normal indication that one should implement IEnumerable is that the class is one where it would make sense to say "foreach foo in classItem {foo.do_something();}.

Answer (score -1):

1. IEnumerable is taking advantage of deferred execution as explained here: [IEnumerable vs List - What to Use? How do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work)
2. IEnumerable enable implicit reference conversion for array types which known as Covariance.  Consider the following example:

public abstract class Vehicle
{
}

```
public class Car :Vehicle
{
}

private void doSomething1(IEnumerable<Vehicle> vehicles)
{

}

private void doSomething2(List<Vehicle> vehicles)
{

}

var vec = new List<Car>();
doSomething1(vec); // this is ok 
doSomething2(vec); // this will give a compilation error
```