# C# function parameter Array vs List

Tags: c#, arrays, list, function, parameters

I'm writing a simple C# class that handle SQL queries in a specific contest. Most of the queries will be `SELECT` statement with 3-4 parameters that should be escaped properly, so the function will be something like this

```
public DataTable Select(string query, string[] parameters) {
    # some code
}
```

Should `parameters` be an `Array` or a `List<>`? Is there some best practice when choosing between these two types as function parameter or is it just a matter of preferences?

P.S. I usually prefer `List<>` because of the flexibility but here the possibility to create an `Array` on the fly is a good point.

Comment: If there is any manipulation of the parameters I would go with a List as resizing arrays is expensive.  If no resizing is necessary i would stick with an array.

Comment: Instead of "escaping" parameters use sql-parameters.

Comment: my advice : dont write this kind of generic data access stuff. its a waste of time. etiher make a db specifc repository which returns your objects or use the system.data generic data stuff

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/2975522/3393095

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use IEnumerable, then it can be either since both [`list`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implement this

```
public DataTable Select(string query, IEnumerable<string> parameters)
```

They also both implement `IList` and `ICollection`, which may offer other useful properties as shown by Tim Schmelter in the comments

Comment: IEnumerable<string> you mean

Comment: Hmm, possibly it depends on what the OP wants to restrict to, Possibly `IEnumerable<T>` too, Thanks

Comment: If he wants to include only arrays or lists as mentioned he should use `IList<string>`. Then you can still access them by index without casting and use the `Count` property(yes, array has).

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Thanks, I've updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: Warning: Using IEnumerable<T> can result in unexpected behaviour. See: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/PossibleMultipleEnumeration.html

Answer (score 9):

According to the [Robustness principle, or Postel's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) (emphasis mine):

> Be conservative in what you do, *be liberal in what you accept from others*

In other words, use the "broadest" type possible, the one higher up in the inheritance hierarchy, so as to:

1. demand as little as possible from the user,
2. and give the user as many choices as possible.

In this case:

- if all you need to do is iterate through the collection of parameters, then you should demand from the user an instance of a type that can be iterated: which, in this case, is `IEnumerable<T>`.
- If you needed to add/remove items, then `ICollection<T>` would be the most liberal option
- If, for some reason, you need to access items by index, then you should demand a `IList<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

On top of what nvoig said, I would:

```
public DataTable Select(string query, params string[] parameters)
{
    return Select(query, (IEnumerable<string>)parameters);
}

public DataTable Select(string query, IEnumerable<string> parameters)
{
    return null;
}
```

so that if you have a "static" query, you can use the first overload (because you know at compile time the number of parameters), while if you have a "dynamic" query you can use the second overload with a `string[]` or a `List<string>` or the result of a LINQ expression.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would expect at least one overload that grants me the ability to pass a params array:

```
public DataTable Select(string query, params string[] parameters);
```

That would allow me to call it with parameters like this:

```
Select("SELECT FROM WHERE", "3", "17", "Joe");
```

Anyone having an `IEnumerable<>` could pass it in easily, too:

```
Select("SELECT FROM WHERE", myData.ToArray());
```

Better would be an overload doing this for me.

Answer (score 0):

In general I would use `IEnumerable<T>` if you only read from the sequence.

In this particular context however I'd simply use a `params string[]` or even `params object[]` type since then you can use it like `String.Format`, i.e.

```
var dt = Select("select A from Table where X=? and Y=?", value1, value2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your parameters have all the same type (here string) you can use params keyword with string array.

```
public DataTable Select(string query, params string[] parameters)
```

Thus you can call it like below

```
Select(myQuery, param1, param2, ...);
```