# Arrays VS Lists for massive multi-structure data

Tags: c#, arrays, list, terrain

For a project I'm remaking Minecraft's voxel blocky terran.

Currently im using a 3 key array(`new Block[,,]`) and then i can reference a block using its cords like `BlockList[x,y,z].BlockID` and stuff like that.

But i want infinite terrain which isn't possible with a `array`. So would a `List` be better for this?

> Keep in mind there are ~200k blocks loaded at any given time - I am
>   afraid of looping through each block in the list to find the block
>   requested would be heavy on CPU.

Comment: This is too broad to explain in a single answer, and belongs on the [Game Dev site](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) anyway. You can't hold an infinite terrain in neither a list nor an array. You need to implement some kind of "streaming" algorithm, where the edges of your terrain are streamed in once they become (nearly) visible. How to do so has been discussed in various places on the web, so please share your research.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which is better to use array or List<>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975426/which-is-better-to-use-array-or-list)

Comment: @EhsanAkbar really? Read the question.

Comment: @EvilTak maybe yes

Comment: Nothing is ever infinite.  Your computer will not be able to handle it

Comment: @CodeCaster Didnt even think of doing that. If you post as a answer ill accept it.

Comment: The thing is to add something new when you're near the end so the user experience a never ending terrain.

Comment: Better use a Hashset this is the fastest data structure in .NET https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx

Comment: @Sherlock this might be the best answer. Performance data shows it outperforms both List and Array in speed when thousands of elements are involved. There is still the major problem where I would have to loop through each element in the Hashset to find the one I'm looking for. I cant imagine this would ever be easy on a CPU